# Detecting if something is not in the users viewpoint whilst hidden from an overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

So the example mark-up:

```
<div class="overflow">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>                                
</div>
```

The first `li` and the second `li` are visible to the user. The 3rd is too large to be displayed given the `overflow: hidden`. But as far as jQuery is concerned using:

```
$('.selected').is(':visible')
```

will always return `true` as it doesn't have `display: none` etc.

CSS:

```
.overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 490px;
}
```

Does anybody know how to detect if the element is visible from within the overflow hidden div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to compare the top of the `<li>` item to the `scrollTop()` of the overflow div.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    oScrollTop = $('.overflow').scrollTop();
    var thisItemIsVisible = ($(this).position().top < oScrollTop);
    console.log('This LI is Visible: ' + thisItemIsVisible);
});
```

Note, this code assumes that if any part of the li is visible, the item is visible. You might want to take the li's height into consideration also.

**EDIT**

If your overflow content is `hidden`, `scrollTop` will always be 0, so you should compare the LI's top position to the height of the `overflow` div.

Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/qaGpm/. For the sake of demonstration, I changed the overflow from `hidden` to `visible` ....

Comment: Brilliant idea. Just running through this now, thanks for the prompt reply. One thing though, if my li's are going to be floated left. In otherwords inline i wonder how i can get this to work. I'm thinking using scrollLeft will be redundant as the .overflow's scrollLeft will always be 0.

Comment: This said. I have updated the jsfiddle and it does work if i float them left. 
Frustrating as i can't see to get it to work on the site. Confusing, i have the same mark up and css. I will investigate more.

Comment: Brilliant :) Thanks Dutchie432 So my issue was that the elements li's $(this).position().top was always greater than oScrollTop as the page had about 350px's above the LI and my markup was crap enough so that. argh you know what, it worked. cheers

Comment: So to say what i was trying to say yesterday. Just make sure that the element you are comparing is inside the parents flow. My problem was the LI's were getting the oScrollTop from the top of the page. hence equally 300+. Hopefully if anybody has the same problem this will save them some time

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `elt.scrollTop()` value is greater than the `elt.position().top + elt.height()` of the element.

But take a look at this plugin: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/
Don't know your exact problem but it sounds like it could be useful.

Comment: Hum unfortunately  this is more about the scrolling effect rather than detecting if an element is hidden via the overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask:

```
if($('.selected').css('overflow')=="visible")
{ 
    //DO somthing
}
```

Comment: Still returns true. Cheers for helping though

Comment: you need to use id and not class

Comment: Didn't think this would work with an ID as this is just a selector. Anyway cheers for the help all the same :)

Comment: heh i am sorry to have caused offence.
But, the selected item returns true. I need it, when it is not visible and inside the hidden section of the element to return false.

Comment: if the 'overflow' attribute of the selected element is visible the condition will be true else false. you can change the condition according your needs.